# How can I pass an object property to a route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a local server that I have created to learn and practice my backend coding. I wrote an order schema like this:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  products: [
    {
      _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
      },
      name: { type: String },
      price: { type: Number },
      obs: { type: String, required: false },
    },
  ],
  owner: {
    _id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      unique: false,
    },
    table: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  status: {
    type: Number,
...
});
```

And I have controllers like this that works already:

```
ordersController.get('/status/:status', async (req, res, next) => {
    const findByStatus = await orderService.findByStatus(req.params.status);
    return res.json(findByStatus);
});
```

But I'm trying to get the orders by owner.table, and I don't know how to pass the exact parameter to the route:

```
ordersController.get('/owner/table/:owner.table', async (req, res, next) => {
});
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up concepts.

Params in the URL (e.g. `:status`) are just arbitrary strings.

This would still work

```
ordersController.get('/status/:abcd', async (req, res, next) => {
    const findByStatus = await orderService.findByStatus(req.params.abcd);
    return res.json(findByStatus);
});
```

You have to write a function that will get this data for you, for example `findByOwnerAndTable`

```
ordersController.get('/owner/:owner/table/:table', async (req, res, next) => {
    const findByStatus = await orderService.findByOwnerAndTable(req.params.owner, req.params.table);
    return res.json(findByStatus);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you're looking for is `res.locals`. `res.locals` is an empty object living on your `res` parameter passed between middleware and controllers that is conventionally used to store information needed by other middleware in the chain.

TLDR: Put information you want to access between middleware on `res.locals`.